# Get ORDERBY Faunadb

Tags: faunadb

```
data: [
{
  name: "Ivo Pereira",
  image: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/55932505?v=4",
  email: "ivojosepereira.jr@gmail.com",
  level: "100",
  experience: "70",
  challenges_completed: "1",
  current_experience_to_next_level: "70"
},
{
  name: "Laura pereira",
  image: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86892146?v=4",
  email: "lauramariapereira.23@gmail.com",
  level: "5",
  experience: "0",
  challenges_completed: "0",
  current_experience_to_next_level: "0"
},
{
  name: "Laura pereira maria",
  image: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86892146?v=4",
  email: "lauramariapereira.23@gmail.com.br",
  level: "55",
  experience: "0",
  challenges_completed: "0",
  current_experience_to_next_level: "0"
}
```

]
}

Hi everyone, I did some research but I still haven't found anything to help me.
I want to put the "level" field in descending order, but I can only get this feedback from faunadb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Fauna, you need to use an index to control whether results are in ascending or descending order.

You haven't provided the query that you used that provided the list of documents above, so I'll assume that they are in the `Users` collection.

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "Users_by_level_descending",
  source: Collection("Users"),
  values: [
    { field: ["data", "level"], reverse: true },
    { field: ["ref"] },
  ]
})
```

With that index, you can report all users sorted by `level` descending with this query:

```
Map(
  Paginate(
    Match(Index("Users_by_level_descending"))
  ),
  Lambda(
    ["level", "ref"],
    Get(Var("ref"))
  )
)
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("Users"), "304066349713326592"),
      ts: 1626239118210000,
      data: {
        name: 'Laura pereira maria',
        image: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86892146?v=4',
        email: 'lauramariapereira.23@gmail.com.br',
        level: '55',
        experience: '0',
        challenges_completed: '0',
        current_experience_to_next_level: '0'
      }
    },
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("Users"), "304066330657554944"),
      ts: 1626239100040000,
      data: {
        name: 'Laura pereira',
        image: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86892146?v=4',
        email: 'lauramariapereira.23@gmail.com',
        level: '5',
        experience: '0',
        challenges_completed: '0',
        current_experience_to_next_level: '0'
      }
    },
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("Users"), "304066303135580672"),
      ts: 1626239073800000,
      data: {
        name: 'Ivo Pereira',
        image: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/55932505?v=4',
        email: 'ivojosepereira.jr@gmail.com',
        level: '100',
        experience: '70',
        challenges_completed: '1',
        current_experience_to_next_level: '70'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the order is "better", but not great. Since the `level` field in your data is a string, this result involves string sorting (any string starting with a `1` is less than any string starting with a `5`).

Instead, if your data uses a numeric value for the level, the result should be what you want.

Here's a query to update your data in bulk, up to the default pagination limit of 64 documents:

```
Map(
  Paginate(Documents(Collection("Users"))),
  Lambda(
    "ref",
    Let(
      { doc: Get(Var("ref")) },
      Update(
        Var("ref"),
        {
          data: {
            level: ToInteger(
              Select(["data", "level"], Var("doc"))
            )
          }
        }
      )
    )
  )
)
```

After the update to the `level` field, the query to get the sorted results returns:

```
Map(
  Paginate(
    Match(Index("Users_by_level_descending"))
  ),
  Lambda(
    ["level", "ref"],
    Get(Var("ref"))
  )
)
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("Users"), "304066303135580672"),
      ts: 1626239549120000,
      data: {
        name: 'Ivo Pereira',
        image: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/55932505?v=4',
        email: 'ivojosepereira.jr@gmail.com',
        level: 100,
        experience: '70',
        challenges_completed: '1',
        current_experience_to_next_level: '70'
      }
    },
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("Users"), "304066349713326592"),
      ts: 1626239549120000,
      data: {
        name: 'Laura pereira maria',
        image: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86892146?v=4',
        email: 'lauramariapereira.23@gmail.com.br',
        level: 55,
        experience: '0',
        challenges_completed: '0',
        current_experience_to_next_level: '0'
      }
    },
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("Users"), "304066330657554944"),
      ts: 1626239549120000,
      data: {
        name: 'Laura pereira',
        image: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86892146?v=4',
        email: 'lauramariapereira.23@gmail.com',
        level: 5,
        experience: '0',
        challenges_completed: '0',
        current_experience_to_next_level: '0'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that way too, but I wanted it to be ranked from highest to lowest ex. 100, 80, 55, 5 etc ...

I looked at the fauna documents but I didn't find anything in this result with strings, and it's possible to leave them in alphabetical order. I will try to treat this data with "sort()" from javascript
thank you so much

Comment: The second set of results are in descending order. Isn't that what you asked for? In the firat results, notice that the values for the `level` field are surrounded in quotation marks. In the second results, notice that the values for the `level` field do not have quotation marks. The first are strings, the second are numbers. That type difference affects how these values are sorted.

Comment: Oh I understand, thank you very much and I'm sorry I ended up seeing only the first result